# NEST assembly not found during runtime on dev server

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

When I test a feature that logs to elasticsearch via the NEST library locally, everything is fine. When I try to test on a dev server (deployed via Jenkins) I get this error when the application would log an event:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Nest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=96c599bbe3e70f5d' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I've:

- checked bin directories (both in the jenkins workspace and app) and I see NEST and Elasticsearch.Net dll's
- tried pushing package.config, web.config, and .csproj files
- reinstalling/updating NEST/Newtonsoft
- deleting the `bin` folder on both the build and web server

...and a few other things that I'm probably forgetting.

My next step is to just have nuget reinstall/update all packages in the solution, but that seems like overkill (and I doubt jenkins would be very happy about that).

What am I missing?

**Update:**

I see the packages in the `packages` folder on the build server, but when it's built/deployed to the web server I do not see the dll's in the `bin` folder. They're only needed on one of the Solution's libraries, which is compiled into a dll that I do see in the `bin` folder of the web server.

Comment: Do you have two versions of newtonsoft.json installed in your solution?

Comment: There were, but I updated them all to 7.0.1

Comment: Can you delete bin directory and run build one more time?

Comment: It just occurred to me that I've only done that on the build server and not the web server it's deployed to... I'll report back in just a minute

Comment: Still broken. I checked the bin folder and the dll isn't even there after the restore. I guess the problem is on the build server?

Comment: Depends how/what you are using to build. Do you have logs to share?

Comment: The build server dumps a few thousand lines of console output, and I don't see anything particularly helpful. I saw something about not having .net framework 4.5, so I added it and still no dice.

I can include snippets of the output if you think it would be helpful, but I'm not entirely sure what I'd be looking for